# How to Install CoolProp in python3.9+(windows) and PyDroid3(Android)

Tags: pip, python-3.9, pydroid

I am having trouble installing CoolProp on python 3.9.
It installed perfectly on `python 2.7` and **Thonny** which uses `python 3.7`

When I try to run pip install CoolProp on python 3.9.5 on windows and also on PyDroid3 for android, I come across the following error.

`ERROR: Command Errored Out with exit status 1`

I have tried many tricks like doing

```
Upgrading pip
pip install CoolProp --user
pip -m install CoolProp
py -3 -m pip install CoolProp --user
```

Nothing seems to work.

Using PyDroid3 on Android also gives me the same problem.
[image: Error Message]

While using PIP on the computer, I get a message that reads

```
Building wheels for collected packages: CoolProp
  Building wheel for CoolProp (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing a manual installation of CoolProp.
Following are the instructions to do so:

- First run `pip install Cython` on windows and in PyDroid3, `hamburger menu > pip > Search Libraries > Cython` and install it from there.
- Download CoolProp Sources from either [GitHub](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/releases/tag/v6.4.1) or [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coolprop/files/CoolProp/).
- On both Android and PC, extract the zip files to a separate folder(any folder you wish, I personally create a folder (far away from regularly used folders) called CK_CoolProp_Sources and extract to it and forget about that folder. I did not delete it lest it corrupt something).
- **For PC:**

  - Run command prompt or PowerShell as an administrator.
  - Type in the following commands:

  ```
  cd <The directory where you extracted the zip file to>\CoolProp-6.4.1\wrappers\Python
  ```

  Now It should look like:

  ```
  C:\<The path to extracted>\CoolProp-6.4.1\wrappers\Python>
  ```

  Now type:

  ```
  python setup.py
  ```

  Let it run. It will do everything for you.
- **For Pydroid3:**

  - First change the **screen timeout duration** to the **maximum possible time** to prevent the screen from turning off. Screen turning off and locking will fail the installation (mine failed twice).
  - Click on **Terminal** from within the hamburger menu inside PyDroid3.
  - Type in the following commands:

  ```
  cd <The directory where you extracted the zip file to>\CoolProp-6.4.1\wrappers\Python
  ```

  Now It should look like:

  ```
  /storage/emulated/0/<The path to extracted>/CoolProp-6.4.1/wrappers/Python $
  ```

  Now type:

  ```
  python setup.py
  ```

  Looks like this:
  [image: PyDroid_Shell]
  **Do NOT let the screen turn off coz that will fail the installation and you will have to reopen terminal, navigate to directory and run `python setup.py` again**

  - Once The terminal finishes installation, close PyDroid3 (remove from recent apps list also) and reopen it.
  - Now, go to interpreter (Hamburger menu inside PyDroid3) and type `import CoolProp`
  - If the screen did not turn off during Terminal Installation, It should work and look like this:
    [image: Success]
  - If it doesn't work and gives any errors, `Pydroid3 - Hamburger Menu > Pip > Install(tab) >`  Enter CoolProp in the `Library Name` text field and click install. It will correct the issue. **It will say requirement already satisfied**, but it repairs the installation in the background or something.
    Looks like this:
    [image: Rebuild]
  - It works after that. Reopen PyDroid3 and `hamburger menu > Interpreter`

  `>>> import CoolProp` should work.